# Know The RAM of one Process in Batch file

Tags: batch-file, ram

So far I wrote this code. Which allow me to restart my nodejs server after a certain amount of time.

```
@echo off
:loop
REM nodevars.bat directory
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs 
REM Initialize environment variables 
call nodevars.bat
::PAUSE
cd C:\Tese\JULIUS-ADDON\Versao_32bits\Julius-ADDON_2013_ComDebug
::PAUSE 
REM Initialize Node.JS
start node app.js
::node app.js ::equivalent
REM timeout
timeout /t 86400 > nul
taskkill /f /im node.exe >nul
timeout /t 2 >null 
goto loop
```

Now I want to kill the process when it overcome a certain value in the RAM. Any idea how?

Comment: 1. the null device is called `nul`, your redirection `> null` willcreate a file named `null`; 2. you cannot do arithmetics `24*60*60` within a command, you need to state the result `86400` there...

Comment: @aschipfl thanks for the note. Edited

Comment: You can just use TASKKILL. taskkill /F /IM node.exe /FI "memusage gt 9999"

Comment: @Squashman can you explain better the `/FI "memusage gt 9999"`

Comment: @Squashman that comand only kill node.exe under that condition or all process under that condition?

Comment: eq - equal
ne - not equal
gt - greater than
lt - less than
ge - greater than or equal
le - less than or equal

Comment: That I understand... I am asking if kill **only** nodejs at the given condition or all process at the given condition. I assume that only kill nodejs. Right?

Comment: @jdscardoso, I am not sure what you are not understanding. The code specifies /IM node.exe and memory usage greater than 9999.  Both these conditions would have to be true for TASKKILL to kill the task.  The help file for the TASKKILL command specifically says this for the /IM option. The image name of the process to be terminated. Wildcard '*' can be used to specify all image names.

Comment: Ok, thats what I understanding. Thanks, I only want to be sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92528/discussion-between-jdscardoso-and-squashman).

Answer (score 3):

[Logman](http://ss64.com/nt/logman.html) is your friend.

```
Logman.exe create alert ss64_alert -th "\Process(notepad)\Private Bytes>1482752" -tn "kill_task"
```

this will trigger a scheduled task called `"kill_task"` when bytes taken from notepad process (without .exe suffix) exceed `1482752` (example value)

To create [task](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) `On demand` you can set it somewhen in the past:

```
SCHTASKS /create /tn "kill_task" /tr "C:\Somewhere\killer.bat" /sc ONCE /sd 01/01/1910 /st 00:00
```

To get oriented what is the output format of the [performance counters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-performance-counters.html) in order to set a correct number you can use [typerperf](http://ss64.com/nt/typeperf.html):

```
typeperf "\Process(notepad)\Private Bytes" -si 1 -sc 1
```